# Problem while performing Insert statement

Tags: database, sqlite, blackberry

HI..
I have a database created and having a table inside it..
now when i am inserting a value in my table it doesnot work...
And please tell me how to see the error if occurs in the eclipse plug in . I am very new to blackberry.
now the snippet code for inserting the value is

```
 Database d;

URI myUri = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLite_Guide/", "Mynewdatabase1.db");
            d= DatabaseFactory.create(myUri);
d.close;
Statement s1=d.createStatement("INSERT INTO People(Name,Age)VALUES ('uttam',23)");
s1.prepare();
            s1.execute();
            s1.close();
            d.close();
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the data base before calling `createStatement`? That isn't going to work. Is this the actual code, because the first you're missing the parens on the first call: `d.close;`